# Should we have an animal-ethics tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

This question:
[When is declawing a viable option for cats?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/485/when-is-declawing-considered-an-ethical-option-if-at-all)

May be the beginning of more of these types of questions. Should we have an `ethics` or `animal-ethics` or pet-ethics` tag?

Comment: If at all I'd go with ethics. Prepending 'pet' or 'animal' on a site about pets seems a bit redundant. (applies to most but not all tags of course)

Comment: I got it back to front? @Baarn feel free to edit

Answer (score 3):

No. I don't think so. The ethics you are referring to are human ethics.

[Your answer](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/485/when-is-declawing-considered-an-ethical-option-if-at-all#answer-502) on the linked post lists countries where declawing is illegal (one of them being mine) but in other places, I suppose it is an option.

Another example of a possible ethics related question would be the anything related to the differences between livestock and pets with regard to consumption.

The answers would most likely be "localized" to the specific region of the user so the highest voted community answer may very well be considered *un-ethical* to readers not located in the same region.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that ethical discussions are appropriate here. What I consider ethical is going to vary greatly from what someone else thinks, and we risk having rants and arguments instead of solid questions and answers. I know it is difficult when we are talking about the welfare of the animals we love to put aside our feelings in these matters, but like I said in my other answer regarding g ethical matters, I think it is important to assume good faith and good intentions, and also remember that other people's opinions and ideas may not match your own, but that doesn't make them terrible people.

You also will never get a consensus on what is the correct or most appropriate answer in these cases, as it will vary greatly from place to place and person to person

In general, SE is a place for concrete, factual answers, and ethics runs too close to opinion and such for it to really be viable.

I would hate to see fights or arguments break out just because two people disagree about what is ethical, as there are so many factors that go into those sorts of personal ideals that we really shouldn't try to take a solid stance on it as a site, because there will always be people who may not be on the same page, and it is a very complex and I feel also a personal issue.

Answer (score 0):

As I tried to mention in my answer to [Questions of moral, ethical and legal nature](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176/questions-of-moral-ethical-and-legal-nature/182#182), this is one of the things that is really going to be a problem because of the international nature of the site, and what is considered proper or normal in one culture, may not be another.  Even in my own country (the US), the laws pertaining to some of the items I mentioned are mixed, so you are not going to get a consensus answer to an "ethical" question.

To quote myself:

> I think it is important to avoid reacting with our personal opinions on such, especially in the answers. This simple fact is someone might not actually understand why such a practice is not good for the animal and a calm and objective answer giving the facts is appropriate.

The point I was trying to make here is that the answers need to be based on facts or at least experience based observations to get a point across as to what the proper course of action is, so dragging ethics into the question is inviting an opinion based answer because my ethics might be different than yours.